# Asp core: IHostedService and IHttpClientFactory - best way?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I have asp core app. I use IHostedService for periodic task. I need send periodic http request. This is my code:

```
  class MyService: IHostedService 
  {
    
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _scopeFactory;

    public MyService(IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory)
    {
        _scopeFactory = scopeFactory;
    }        

    private async void DoWork(object state)
    {
        using (var scope = _scopeFactory.CreateScope())
        {
            var clientFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
                "https://api.github.com/repos/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/branches");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
            request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");

            var client = clientFactory.CreateClient();
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
            ...
            
        }
    }
  }
```

Also I added it in my Startup.cs

```
services.AddHttpClient();
```

This is working. But I'm not sure if this is the best performance solution. Any tips?

Comment: As far as I know, the services.AddHttpClient will register the service as the Singleton not the scope, that means there is no need to create the service as scope, we could directly use it in the DoWork. Could you please tell me why you register the service as the scope? Besides, it seems you just call the background service once when the application started. Could you please tell me how many request you will send in the background service.

Comment: I am new to the asp core. This is an example that I found on the net. how do i do it right?

Comment: In my opinion, there is no need to inject the IHttpClientFactory again by using `scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService`, you could use below example to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am new to the asp core. This is an example that I found on the net. how do i do it right?

If you want to run background service to send the request in asp.net core, I suggest you could directly inject the httpClientFactory instead of using `ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService` to inject it again.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

1. Make sure you have add the  AddHttpClient service into the startup.cs

   services.AddHttpClient();

2.Add below codes into the worker.cs:

```
public class Worker : IHostedService
{
    private IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory;

    public Worker(IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory) {

        httpClientFactory = _httpClientFactory;

    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
         DoWork("test");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    
    }

    private async void DoWork(object state)
    {

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:9012/");
        //request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3+json");
        //request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "HttpClientFactory-Sample");
        var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        int i = 0;
    }
 }
```

Result:

[image]

More details about how to use asp.net core background service, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio).